# find the minimum number of sets

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Let's explain my question with example I have some integer sets for example

- S<sub>1</sub> = {2,3}
- S<sub>2</sub> = {2, 5}
- S<sub>3</sub> = {4, 5}
- S<sub>4</sub> = {4}
- S<sub>5</sub> = {5}

And I have sample set S<sub>sample</sub> with 4 elements {2, 3, 4, 5}.

So now I want to find minimum number of sets to build S<sub>sample</sub>. In this case I can use S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>3</sub> because S<sub>1</sub> contains {2, 3} and S<sub>3</sub> contains {4, 5}. Their union is equivalent to S<sub>sample</sub>. We can choose sets S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>4</sub>, and S<sub>5</sub> but that isn't a sufficient answer so how can find this minimum number of sets?

Isn't it a kind of knapsack problem?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771682/find-minimum-number-of-sets

Comment: @gnat Will [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/268032/106929) survive or the one on SO, or both?

Comment: @Wolf I believe it's a better fit here. Although it's up to our and SO moderators to sort this out (I flagged it for their attention)

Comment: I flagged for closure at StackOverflow. In the future OP algorithm questions are better suited for this site over StackOverflow however you have the choice to post at one or the other.  Don't cross post questions across sites unless they are tailored to the sites audience.

Answer (score 4):

It's similar to the knapsack problem in that it is NP-complete. This particular instance is the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). There are a number of ways to solve this but only by approximation. [Integer Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) yields a reasonably fast method of approximation.